# Find recursive, hierarchical structures in a sequence

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find structures that are both recursive and hierarchical from a sequence. I did come across the [sequitur algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequitur_algorithm) but it only returns hierarchical structures.

Consider the following sequence as an example: `abcbcabc`

What sequitur returns:

```
0 -> 1 2 1
1 -> a 2
2 -> b c
```

Required output:

```
0 -> 1 1
1 -> a 2
2 -> b c | b c 2
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this: in `2`, doesn't `b c 2` imply (at least) a `bcbc` sequence in the input? Also, how does the `0` encoding `1 1` know which alternative to pick in `2` - or maybe that doesn't matter for your application? Maybe if you explain how this is to be used?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes, I don't care about reconstructing the sequence from the rules. I am interested in finding out the underlying substructures of the sequence

Comment: What you say in your comment is contradicting your question where you are saying you want hierarchy and sequence.

Comment: @Aldert I am not sure how it is contradicting. I am interested in the recursive, hierarchical substructures in the sequence like the example I have provided in the required output. What I don't care about is then reconstructing the original sequence back from the rules.

Comment: I thought in a hierarchy, each element is ordered and appearing only once. It looks like you are looking for all possible combinations with the OR. I believe by doing so you lost the logic, only the reader can decide on the OR.

Comment: You don't need a recursive rule to describe the structures of any finite sequence, and since the recursion is unnecessary for the description there's any number of ways you could include it. For instance, you could tack recursion onto any production from sequitur, and it will still describe the sequence. What makes the grammar you've chosen to describe the sequence as 'required output' the correct one? Right now this doesn't sound like a well-defined problem.